# Have I issued my Exchange Server 2010 certificate correctly with internal CA?

Tags: ssl-certificate, exchange-server

I got the following Event 12018 The STARTTLS certificate will expire soon on my Exchange 2010 server. A relatively common event I thought and I read many blogs and articles, including extensive but not particularly helpful TechNet articles. Through trial, error and happenstance I simply issued a generic request and set the resulting certificate to have all exchange roles (I have a single hostname).

It's processing email and ActiveSync as expected, but was this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the detailed steps of what I did :

I used the PowerShell commandlet (Exchange Management Shell from start menu) and issued this following comandlet with no parameters

New-ExchangeCertificate

This echoes a thumbprint

Then I opened the Exchange Management Console (also from start menu) and select Server Configuration from the left pane (note: it takes a while for the snapin to load). I then located the certificate issued (checking the thumbprint echoed from the commandlet). I selected the "assign services to certificate", processed the wizard, selecting all services.

I then delete the certificate that had the warning and tested the server. I then rebooted the server to be sure the changes were persistent.